# time delay for file insertion using google cloud storage api

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am attempting to use google cloud storage api to save image files. 
It usually takes 1 to 3 seconds to send image insertion request and get the reply back from the google server per an image, but sometimes(like 1 per 1500 tries) it takes very long time, such as more than 10 minutes.(I checked that a case waits about 50 minutes from the request to retrieve the insertion result) Since google console doesn't provide delay logs, I cannot check anything about it.

This delay bothers my job to be finished in time. I want to know the reason for the delay.

I works with java, and the maximum size of an image is 2 mega bytes, and my code uses google providing api.

Also I checked the readTimeout is 20sec and connectTimeout is 20sec which are given by the provided class of google. But this delayed cases never provide any exception message, just make my program be blocked.

please give me any clue about it...
thank you.

maven :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-storage</artifactId>
        <version>v1-rev82-1.22.0</version>
</dependency>
```

java code :

```
StorageObject objectMetadata = new StorageObject()
        .setName(imgName)
        .setAcl(Arrays.asList(new ObjectAccessControl()
                .setEntity("allUsers")
                .setRole("OWNER")));
ByteArrayContent byteArrayContent = new ByteArrayContent(null,imgBytes);

GoogleCredential credential = getMyCredential();

if (credential.createScopedRequired()) {
    Collection<String> scopes = StorageScopes.all();
    credential = credential.createScoped(scopes);
}

JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

Storage storage = new Storage.Builder(GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(), jsonFactory, credential)
        .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();

Storage.Objects.Insert insertRequest =
        storage.objects().insert(bucketName,objectMetadata,byteArrayContent);
insertRequest.execute(); //delay occurs here
```

Comment: Are you doing this from inside App Engine, GCE, or some other machine not in the Google cloud?

Comment: @BrandonYarbrough, hi. The code is running at the other machine, the company's server that I work for.