# how to control time delay in google storage api service

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I previously asked about time delay of google storage api service since file insertion takes too long sometimes.(link : [time delay for file insertion using google cloud storage api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40011810/time-delay-for-file-insertion-using-google-cloud-storage-api) ) 
Cause no one answered about it, I want to change my question little bit...

Is there any method in the storage api to control waiting time between sending a request to a google storage and getting a result? I want to kill a task taking longer than I expected.

Thank you.

Comment: You just want to terminate the connection? What library or tool are you using to connect to GCS?

Comment: Here is my library dependency : 
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-storage</artifactId>
        <version>v1-rev82-1.22.0</version>
I want to terminate the connection when it takes too long.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the Java Google API Client Library. To get the connection to terminate after a certain amount of time, you'll want to [configure timeouts](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/errors#timeouts):

```
private HttpRequestInitializer setHttpTimeout(final HttpRequestInitializer requestInitializer) {
  return new HttpRequestInitializer() {
    @Override
    public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) throws IOException {
      requestInitializer.initialize(httpRequest);
      httpRequest.setConnectTimeout(3 * 60000);  // 3 minutes connect timeout
      httpRequest.setReadTimeout(3 * 60000);  // 3 minutes read timeout
    }
  };

GoogleCredential credential = ....

final Storage analytics = Storage.builder(new NetHttpTransport(), jsonFactory, setHttpTimeout(credential)).build();
```